# Train NER model avoiding outofmemory error

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to train a NER model using the [stanford-nlp library](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml#Download). I have a file in the needed format with a size of 6GB. The configuration file:

```
usePrevSequences=true
useClassFeature=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useSequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
useTypeySequences=true
useDisjunctive=true
noMidNGrams=true
serializeTo=ner-model50.ser.gz
maxNGramLeng=6
useNGrams=true
usePrev=true
useNext=true
maxLeft=1
trainFile=trainData
map=word=0,answer=1
useWord=true
useTypeSeqs=true
```

Every sentence is splitted by empty line as suggested in the documentation. So when I run the command with `mx25g`:

```
java -mx25g -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop config.prop
```

I got the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

From the [FAQ page](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#k) of the library it is suggested to split the file to multiple files in case of memory error.

To do that you need to change the config file by using the `trainFileList` option instead of `trainFile` option. Now I have multiple files of around 250MB each one. I got the following error running the same command:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

So it seems that splitting the files didnt help. Do you think spliting to even smaller files will help? or it doesnt matter?Any way to overpass that problem? Any insight is useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem as yours, one of My senior suggested me to use
**-Xmx** instead of **-mx** to specify maximum heap size according to your machine RAM & swap size.
You can also reduce no. of entity classes or mergeTags if using IOB encoding because space used exponentially increases with increase in entity classes.

> java -Xmx**g  -cp stanford-ner.jar
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop ner.prop

this worked for me.